# Ctrl+h causing backspace instead of help in emacs on cygwin

Tags: emacs, cygwin, keymap, backspace

I want to access the help for a command by using ctrl+h in emacs, but it keeps deleting the previous character. I googled it, and apparently ctrl+h is backspace in a terminal. How do I remove this key mapping? I use regular backspace, and I want to access the emacs help using ctrl+h. I'm using cygwin and GNU Emacs 23.3.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cygwin's default backspace keycode was changed from `^H` to `^?` a couple of years ago to stop this from happening. Are you using an old Cygwin version or the no-longer-maintained rxvt, which still does use `^H` by default?

Comment: Yea, I'm using rxvt (nice guess!). Will I have to switch to a different terminal or do you know how to change it for rxvt?

Comment: Give [mintty](http://mintty.googlecode.com) a try, which has recently become Cygwin's default terminal. Like rxvt, it doesn't require an X server, but it provides xterm-compatible terminal emulation, Unicode support, and a more Windows-native UI with an options dialog.

With rxvt, the command line option `-backspacekey '^?'` should do the trick.

Comment: I think I tried this when you responded and it didn't work (not 100% sure that I did), but I've switched to mintty since then so I'll accept your answer.